# Xcode 11.1 how to install iOS14 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I try to download xcode12 beta and copy the `iPhoneSimulator14.0.sdk` to `/Applications/Xcode_11.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`
And I restart the xcode11.1, nothing happen.
How to install iOS14 simulator? 
Thanks.

[image: path]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The iOS 14 SDK is only supported with Xcode 12.

If you want to use the iOS 14 Simulator Runtime from Xcode 11, the easiest way is to launch Simulator.app from Xcode 12 and boot the simulator device you want from within Simulator.app.  It will then appear as a run destination in your older Xcode.

Comment: I can't see iOS 14 simulator in Xcode beta 4. Any idea?

Comment: Does this solution really work? I booted iPhoneX iOS14.0 simulator from Xcode 12. How will that add it as a target in the Xcode11.5 that I normally use?

Comment: @iOSer Did you get a way to add this ?

Comment: @jeremy-huddleston-sequoia iOS 14 Simulator doesn't appear on Older version of XCode even after opening it from XCode 12 version. Can you explain more about the way to do this ?

Comment: It wasn't appearing for me either, until I restarted my macbook. Then it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Mac, this is what caused them to appear for me